# In android studio trying to use fused location provider client, but I get this error message. Trying to create a concrete class and use it in main

Tags: android, android-activity

[Toast message of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAy01.jpg)

Concrete class:

```
'''public class MarkedSpot extends AppCompatActivity {

private String owner;

private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;

public MarkedSpot(){
    this.owner = "";

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    /* Above is where the exception is thrown, when assigning fusedLocationProviderClient */



    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MarkedSpot.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MarkedSpot.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 45);
        }
    }




}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void updateGPS(){

    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MarkedSpot.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);

    switch (requestCode){
        case 45:
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            updateGPS();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"This app requires permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}'''

For some reason having a difficult time posting, this is my first so bear with me. I am not sure how much longer i have to continue this current line of wording because for some reason it will not allow me to due to "mostly coding"

Comment: This class extends `Activity`. Do you want to create an `Activity` or do you want to create a POJO class?

Comment: also, you can't just post a bunch of code. You are expected to describe your problem and explain what you did and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in the constructor needs to be moved into `onCreate()`. Override `onCreate()` and put the code you have in the constructor in there. Make sure to call `super.onCreate()`.

You should not have a constructor for an `Activity`, Android sets up the instance and then calls `onCreate()`. Do your initialization in there.